# firebase notification allow send from my domain only

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

firebase notification allow sending from my domain only
Now I can send the notification with the postman and if anyone with the key can send notifications on my device how to prevent this?
I need to make sure that with the key notification can send only from my website

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restrict sending of FCM messages to a single domain, a single app, or a single user. Anyone who has the FCM Server Key can send messages to all users of your app.

The key to ensuring that only you can send messages to your users is to keep the FCM server key secret. So don't expose it in the app that you ship to your users.

This means that if you want users to be able to *send* messages to other users, that you'll have to do so from a trusted environment in between these users. The trusted environment can be your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. The important bit is that the FCM Server Key is only present in this trusted environment that you control access to, so it can't be taken by malicious users.